# Would it be correct to use Present Continuous?

Tags: present-continuous

Let's imagine the following situation. At school, a foreign language is studied for 11 years, starting from the 1st grade. The student can choose one of several foreign languages to study it. I ask a third grader what language he is learning (**CONTEXT: at this moment he is not studing anything, he is drinking tea, for example**). Is it OK to use Present Continuous in the question, for example "*What language are you learning?*" ? Here we are talking about a temporary action, we know when it started (1st grade) and when it will end (after 11th grade), so it seems that I can use **Present Continuous**. But it seems to me that I am mistaken. How would you ask the question? Explain your decision, please.

Comment: Yes, the continuous tense is used when speaking of an ongoing course of study.

Comment: @KateBunting great, thanks, Kate!